# How do I set a responsive li size ratio of 2:1 containing different sized images in grid

Tags: html, css

.gallery contains 12 li with images varying in size. Currently the gallery grid displays all li as square as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/0nef5wjo/3/ I'm struggling to learn how to set the li as a rectangle 2:1 and have images of different size fill the width and bleed height if an image file is too tall. How do I accomplish this?

```
    .gallery {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 0.75rem;
grid-auto-flow: dense;
padding: 40px;
list-style: none;
background: white;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

li {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 15px;
display: block;
object-fit: cover;
box-shadow: 0em 0em .5em rgba(0 0 0 0.75);
}


img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

You can't just "make the images fit" and change their size... but you can place them as a background image instead.

```
.thing {
  background-image url(here); /* but should be set inline in the HTML */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Here's a fork of your example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/nox954yt

Good luck!

Comment: OMG Thank you! your comments were super helpful and makes things much more clear.